# How do you eliminate or lessen feedback?

Tags: mixer, feedback

I have a 24 channel mackie mixing board, and I am trying to run two shure super 55s through the board and into two EV 1 inch monitors. I am getting a large amount of feedback whenever I try to get any volume out of my mics. Is there any special way to set the channels to get more volume with less feedback? Or are there any tips for getting more volume without having a large amount of feedback?

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to hunt down the source of the feedback and try to minimize it. There are a few things that need some clearing up.

When you say 1 inch monitors, are these local monitors at your board or the house PA system you are mixing into?

What output of the console are you using?

What kind of setting are you in?

What is the room like?

One thing you can do is try to take a bit off the preamp and push the fader a bit more. If you have a low pass filter on your EQ section use it to roll of some of the top end which may help a bit as well. You may also be pushing the whole system to much in which case you may need to change your configuration for the room you are in. More details on the situation will help us answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

The number one name of the game is EQs.  Feedback occurs when a portion of the sound you are amplifying makes its way back in to a microphone and is amplified again.  It takes on the sound of whatever frequency was picked up louder than it initially went in.

In order to eliminate feedback, you need to break the feedback loop by either altering the position or orientation of the microphones so that they do not pick up the sound from the speakers (point it away from the speakers, preferably behind them), by altering the orientation or position of the speakers so that they don't pick up the mic (point them away from the microphone), and if those don't work, by EQing the sound of the microphone (through channel EQs) or the PA (through 31 band EQs) in order to reduce the sensitivity of the system to whatever sound is feeding back.

If you don't know what frequency it is, you can either sweep for it (if you have a parametric EQ) by turning down the gain on the parametric channel and altering the frequency until the feedback goes away.  You can then turn it back up until just before you start noticing a ringing sound, which is what you hear before feedback.  Alternately, you can use a tone generator or a frequency analyzer application on your phone to get a rough idea of the tone that is causing problems and turn down that frequency until the problem stops.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously make sure the mics are not in front of the speakers. I have been using Shure Super 55's for a year now and have found the best way to sing with them is to have the gain turned down low and for the performer to sing within an inch from the mic. They will need good microphone technique. Supercardioid pickup pattern afterall. When you use these mics the right way they are great. They take getting used to though, not as accessible as something like an SM58.

Comment: Even with SM58s they should be singing within an inch of the mic.  The rule of "thumb" I always tell people is that if you can wrap your hand below the cage of an SM58 and can't stick out your thumb and touch your chin, it is too far away.  I've even suggested that the worst offenders actually keep their thumb on their chin.